# Creating a rotatable 3D path in svg

Tags: svg, 3d

I'm working with some geo data and creating an svg path from lat,lon and elevation.

I've got two svg paths which are working, one displaying the lat/lon and the other which is elevation.

What I'm trying to do is create a 3d path which I can than twist, turn and morph to go from a 2d profile to a 2d overhead and different points in between.

I've setup up a code-pen which shows the two working paths, and my attempt at a 3d which includes x,y,z axis. I can't seem to find anything which says I am permitted to provide a z axis in svg path, but figured it was worth a shot.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRZNXW

The differences between the path lines are

```
<path d="Mx,y lat,lon">
<path d="Mi,z index,elevation">
<path d="Mx,y,z lat,lon,elevation">
```

Does anybody know if what I am trying to do in svg is possible? Or why I am showing the strange behaviour in my 3rd path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is a 2D image format.  You cannot create 3D paths.

Comment: Thanks to this https://github.com/kovacsv/JSModeler/wiki/SVG-To-3D-Tutorial , you can.

Comment: That's a little different. That code is using an SVG as a source of 2D data that it then converts to 3D and renders in a Canvas.